# Wrapper around plot() function to use varargin

Tags: matlab

I have a several datasets which are Nx2 size. Say, it is called dat1. I want to make a wrapper function `myplot()` to plot it using `plot()` function without doing `plot(dat1(:,1), dat1(:,2))` every time.

It is not a problem, but I want to be able to use all the other properties like `'LineWidth'`, marker etc. the same way as `plot()`.

How do I make a wrapper `myPlot()` that can interpret the variable arguments similar to `plot()`? It should look like this:

`myPlot(dat1, 'rx')` should translate to `plot(dat1(:,1), data1(:,2),'rx')`

`myPlot(data1, 'Linewidth',2)` should translate to `plot(dat1(:,1), data1(:,2),'Linewidth',2)`

Edit: Thanks. Found an answer elsewhere

```
function h = myPlot(varargin)
  dat = varargin{1};
  h = plot(dat(:,1), dat(:,2), varargin{2:end});
```

Comment: Use a cell array. Check this out for inspiration. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/8266-convert-array-to-argument-list

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
myPlot = @(data, varargin) plot(data(:,1), data(:,2), varargin{:})
```

This creates an anonymous function as per @MichaelTr7's answer, but makes it more flexible by accepting `varargin`, and then expanding that in the call to `plot`. (This is a standard technique for passing through extra arguments unchanged to another function).

Comment: That's not right - `plot(data)` plots multiple lines, one per column; `plot(data(:,1), data(:,2))` uses the first column of `data` as the `XData`, and the second column as the `YData`.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood something in the question. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

Using an anonymous functions/function handles might be a way of creating a sort of wrapper function. In this case all your expected inputs can go into the `@()`. This can be reused as many times as you like after the initial definition.

```
%Function definition%
myPlot = @(Data,Line_Width,Marker_Type) plot(Data(:,1),Data(:,2),'LineWidth',Line_Width,'Marker',Marker_Type);

%Random test data%
N = 100;
dat = rand(N,2);
myPlot(dat,2,'*');
```